# Solution of quantile function

Tags: functions

Find the quantile function of 
$$q=F(x)=[(1-\exp(-bx))^c]*[1+d-d*(1-\exp(-bx))^c]$$ , where $b, c$ are positive real
 and $-1<d<1$.
Its answer is 
[image: gif]

Any help/hint is most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the term in the first square bracket, call it $z$, then you have a quadratic in $z$.
Solve for $z$ then it is easy to solve for $x$. The 2d is in the wrong place in your solution, just a type I guess. Not sure why just one root of the quadratic is used. Also think about what happens when d<0.

Comment: thanks your help is much appreciated,and -1<d<1.

Comment: when d<0 the denominator will mean you are taking the c-th root of a -ve quantity.

Comment: when i said -1<d<1 , i really meant abs(d)<=1. It was my mistake.